# Does MoleculeValue use a non-standard definition of bridgehead atoms?

Tags: chemistry

According to many sources (e.g., [this](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/%7Eharding/IGOC/B/bridgehead.html)), there should be four bridgehead atoms in phenanthrene. But `MoleculeValue` returns an empty list.

```
"phenanthrene" // (Molecule /* {MoleculeValue[#, "BridgeheadAtoms"] &, MoleculePlot} /* Through /* Row)
```

How does Wolfram Language define a bridgehead atom?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition used for ["BridgeheadAtoms"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculeValue.html#1167168805) is "atoms common to rings sharing at least two bonds".

This definition is specifically designed to include only bridged compounds and exclude fused rings. You can see this with

```
MoleculePlot3D[m = Molecule[#], {m["BridgeheadAtoms"]}] & /@ {"norbornane", "decalin"}
```

[image]

If you want to include fused rings you can use a SMARTS pattern to find any atom with three or four ring bonds, as suggested [here](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/discussions/5052#discussioncomment-2265012):

```
MoleculePlot3D[m = Molecule[#], {MoleculePattern["[x{3-4}]"]}] & /@ {"norbornane", "decalin"}
```

[image]

Comment: That makes sense. At some point, I should just buckle down and learn to use SMARTS.

Comment: I am trying to make it so you don't have to, but haven't covered everything that SMARTS can cover in WL syntax yet.  So you could write the smarts `"[R{3-4}]` as `Atom[_, "RingCount" -> (3|4)]`, because `R` stands for ring memberships.  But `x` stands for ring connectivity - the number of ring bonds from an atom, and I now see I should enable that in WL.  Eventually I want a convertor from SMARTS to WL.